# Error in PageAdapter and viewpager in eclipse android?

Tags: java, android, tabs

So i am new developer in Android and started on a projct in which at a pont I needed to make scrollable tabs (like in google play store). So I used the following code. I can't work out the error. I use eclipse ADT bundle(like everyone else of course)!

Here is the mainActivity

```
    package com.deathreaper.main;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

    import com.deathreaper.com.tabs.Tab1;
    import com.deathreaper.com.tabs.Tab2;
    import com.deathreaper.com.tabs.Tab3;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager= null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    }
}
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{



    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment= null;
        switch (arg0) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new Tab1();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Tab2();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Tab3();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }`


}
```

The error is in line 25 `viewPager.setAdapter(MyAdapter(fragmentManager));` i.e. the last line in `manActivity` class.
The error it is giving is as follows
"The method `MyAdapter(Fragment)` is undefined for the type `Mainactivity`"
Please if anyone could help, it would be really awesome!Thanks:D :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `new` keyword.

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
```